# How to fit Anomaly Detection model to imbalanced time series data(Zero Inflected time series data)?

Tags: unbalanced-classes, zero-inflation, anomaly-detection

I'm doing a predictive modeling for predicting anomalies in the sensors data. For this I'm using the twitter AnomalyDetection package in R. We are getting ton of data from sensors for every day. For every 5 sec we get a one data point from sensor. we are averaging this data over 2 min. We have a one sensor which sends the data between 0(min value for sensor) and 12(max value for sensor). But most of the times sensor sends the zero's(~98%). We are building AnomalyDetection model on this data. What I think, this model trains on the most of the zeros's. When we used this model for new data points it gives an false alarm even if new data point lies between min and max of sensor value.

For example : Descriptive statistics for this sensor data as below
[image]

Because of the most of the data points are zero's summary statistics look like this. Below is the plot of the data by day.
[image]

What I believe that if we give any value between min and max of sensor value to the model, model does not have to declare it anomaly but the trained model declaring it as an anomaly point. so it is false alarm.

So how to train the model on less event data? Here event is point out of the control limit.

Comment: Maybe you could add a code example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Without more information I can't give much specific guidance, but from looking at the [AnomalyDetectionTs documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/anomalyDetection/versions/1.0/topics/AnomalyDetectionTs), here are some things you could try:

1. If the algorithm is giving you too many false positives, try decreasing the `alpha` and `max_anoms` parameters
2. If the algorithm is finding too few anomalies, try increasing the `alpha` and `max_anoms` parameters
3. If the anomalies the algorithm is finding don't match the regions you were expecting, try adjusting the `direction` and `longterm` parameters

Comment: Non zero value is not the anomaly in this case. We are averaging the this 5 sec data over 2 min for data reduction. Even if we have averaged over 2 min it is a large data set. We have some specified values for min and max values of sensors. we declare the point as anomaly if it is greater the 3 sigma of average. But min value for sensor is zero and maximum value is 12, and in our data set most of the data points are zero's(~98). So how to train the anomaly detection model on such data.

Comment: You should add that information to your question at the top. How is the fitted model underperforming? What were you expecting? You need to provide additional details if you want useful feedback, otherwise we're just guessing. The model implemented by AnomalyDetectionTs is pretty basic, it's just removing periodic variation and large-scale trends, and looking for samples which are significantly higher/lower than some cutoff. The paper describing the algorithm is here: https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/hotcloud14/hotcloud14-vallis.pdf

Comment: I updated my answer as best I could given the information available